# Flash builder include files in Release build

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder

My setup: `Flash Builder 4.7`

I have text file "1.txt" in folder "folder1" I added to project tree in Flash Builder.
I want to read this file in runtime using file stream on iOS device.
Question:

1. How to make flash builder pack this folder while exporting release build and running on device.
2. How to access this directory to to read this file.

(I can succesfully open "1.txt" runtime when running/debugging on device/air simulator if I place "folder1" in `<path to my app>\bin-debug\` but it still doesn't work after "Export release build" action).
**Update:**
When i run `Export Release Buid` dialog i don't get `folder1` on `Package Contents` tab, why????

Comment: Have you ticked "1.txt" in Flash Builder Project Properties -> Flex Build Packaging -> Apple iOS -> Package Contents tab?

Comment: it is ticked by default(whole folder). I dont know how create File object pointing to this folder.

Comment: post the code you are using to load the txt file

Comment: fileStream.open(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("folder1" + File.separator + n + ".txt"), FileMode.READ);

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.
I've put my folder in src node in project tree. I don't think it is correct way to do this but it works...