# Flash Builder embedding files into app like flash IDE?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I'll try to make this simple :
If I create an AIR app from the Flash IDE, I can choose to embed folder in my package. Then I can load the files using 'app:/'+filename. Everything is ok.
I have to move to Flash Builder because I can't test workers in the IDE (thanks Adobe). My issue is that, if I test/debug from Flash Builder, it does a stream error when calling 'app:/'+filename. If I launch the test in the IDE from FB, it works but the Workers don't. I should mention, the reason I'm using this method is that I have so many graphical assets, it's just easier to maintain/update this way instead of using [Embed.. ] for all my items, and it just works in the IDE...

I've added my folder to my sources locations in Flash Builder, still it seems I cannot use the 'app:/' thing.

How can I make this work so I don't change my code and still use 'app:/'? FB is such a confusing program...

edit : I tested again the workers in the IDE build launched by FB (the test in flash IDE icon), I can trace its state with :

```
worker.start();
worker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE, this._handleWorkerState);

private function _handleWorkerState(__e:Event):void{
        trace(__e.currentTarget.state);
}
```

traces 'new' then 'running'. But for some reason, it doesn't send or receive any data from any message channel, which, again, works in FB4.7 when i run a debug but doesn't find my files....

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/foldername..
```

So basically, I'm looking for a solution to at least one of my problems :)

EDIT :
So ok. Here it is, one issue was due to the wrong debugger version installed (for the workers part). So I can now work and compile in the IDE again. I haven't found an answer to why 'app:/' doesn't work from FB4.7. So that would be the remaining question.

Comment: If you go to Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Packaging -> Package Contents, is your folder listed and ticked?

Comment: There is no 'Flex build packaging' in Project -> Properties. This is FB 4.7 btw. Also project is set as a Flash IDE project.

Comment: Ah apologies, I'm using 4.6, not really familiar with 4.7

Comment: Odd, [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-13a250c812e8e9b5533-7ff1.html) and [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752680/flash-builder-include-files-in-release-build) seem to indicate `Flex Build Packaging` should be available in `Project Properties`...

Answer (score 1):

One option since you have Flash IDE is to create a library with all of your images. Drop all your images into the library in Flash and export them for actionscript. Then publish and create a a SWC. Then you can use the swc, which is kind of like a zip file for display objects, in flashbuilder and access them like:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new imageExportedForAS3_1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a top level folder in your flex project called for example images, copy all of your images into that folder, then every time you need to load an image, just use the source attribute and use the absoulte rute, for example.

```
<mx:Image source="@Embed(source='../images/pic.png')"
```

I have never used the app:/ sentence before! Good luck!